# variadic variadic template template specialisation error

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

Im trying to create a template which given a set of meta-functions and an metafunction, adds this methafunction to the provided set.

```
template<template<template<typename...> class...> class Dest,
                  template<typename...> class FirstTpl,
                  template<typename...> class ...Tpls>
struct template_push_front
{
};

template<template<template<typename...> class...> class Dest,
                  template<typename...> class FirstTpl,
                  template<typename...> class ...Tpls>
struct template_push_front<Dest, FirstTpl, Dest<Tpls...>> : Dest<FirstTpl, Tpls...>
{
};
```

- Meta-functions are represented as variadic templates.
- Dest is an existing set of meta-functions
- Tpls is the Dest content
- FirstTpl is the meta-function to be added to the begining of Dest

When compiling I get  the following error:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<template<class ...> class ...<template-parameter-2-1> > class Dest, template<class ...> class FirstTpl, template<class ...> class ... Tpls> struct template_push_front’
struct template_push_front<Dest, FirstTpl, Dest<Tpls...>> : Dest<FirstTpl, Tpls...>

expected a class template, got ‘Dest<Tpls ...>’
```

on the line

```
struct template_push_front<Dest, FirstTpl, Dest<Tpls...>> : Dest<FirstTpl, Tpls...>
```

concerning the

```
Dest<Tpls...>
```

token

I understand that the compiler does not recognize Dest< Tpls... > as a class template. What can I do to make it compile?

Comment: Could you give us an example of how you want to use that?

Comment: May be you can post a more complete example - including how you use it?

Comment: I guess you want something like `template<template<template<class...> class...> class Dest,
                  template<class...> class FirstTpl,
                  class List>
struct template_push_front
{
};`. Then you can use the specialization you provided (w/o change). However, the first template parameter of the *primary* template shouldn't be required at all, and I'd rather swap the positions of `FirstTpl` and the list of metafunctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing how I'd like to use such a thing, I came up with the following:

Exemplary definitions of metafunctions and some list of metafunctions:

```
template<class L, class R>
struct some_binary_metafunction {};

template<class T>
struct some_unary_metafunction {};

template< template<class...> class... MFs >
struct some_list_of_metafunctions {};
```

The `push_front` mechanism:

```
template< class List, template<class...> class MF >
struct push_front;

template< template< template<class...> class... > class ListT,
          template<class...> class... ListEntries,
          template<class...> class MF >
struct push_front< ListT<ListEntries...>, MF >
{
    using type = ListT<MF, ListEntries...>;
};
```

Test case / example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void print_type()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    using my_list = some_list_of_metafunctions<some_binary_metafunction,
                                               some_binary_metafunction,
                                               some_unary_metafunction>;
    using result = push_front<my_list, some_unary_metafunction>::type;

    print_type<result>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your example works. The error in my code was in the first template definition.